# Binding "Highcharts" events in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm trying to bind a function in the load event of Highchart (In Rails).

```
raw "options.chart.events.load = abc();"
```

I have an alert in the function abc(), which gets fired but, the graph is not rendered with following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'load' of undefined
```

Function defination:

```
function abc(){
  alert('Hi');
}
```

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: If you are using Jquery you can call this as `$(chart).bind('load', abc());`

Comment: Have you defined events object in your options/chart structure? You refer to field which is undefined. Let me know how your options object looks like.

Comment: I have defined it like this
`
LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.events({
        :load => ''
      })
end`

and in my view I'm using:

`
= raw "options.chart.events.load = abc()"`

Comment: Well, but generally you have no defined options object anywhere, so how you can refer to events, when options is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and found this solution

```
<%= high_chart("some_id", LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('column') do |f|
    f.options(
          chart: {
            :events => {
              :load => "function(){ return false; }".js_code
            }
          }
      )
<% end %>
```